# How can I tell if a user is *not* logged in via Google Sign-In (OAuth2)?

Tags: oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

I have a web page that is sensitive to whether or not a user is logged in. I'm using the Google Sign-In Javascript SDK. When the user arrives at this page, I would like to display an interstitial ("loading...") and then either 1) render the page if the user is logged in or 2) redirect the user elsewhere if they are not.

Google's SDK fires an event when it detects that the user is logged in... but how can I know that the user isn't logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auth instance allows you to check whether a user is signed in or not.

[`gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2googleauth)

You can't do this right at page load since the `GoogleAuth` instance needs to be initialized first, so you will need something like this:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({...});

auth2.then(function () {
  if (!auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {

  }
});
```

Calling auth2.init will sign-in previous users automatically before calling your function.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing! And I thought I had read the sign-in reference page carefully, sigh. Thanks.